# Django - How to register a single template tag for multiple templates?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to register a `@register.inclusion_tag` for multiple templates?

for example:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/components/tags_list.html',
                        takes_context=True)
def tags_list(context):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return {
        'request': context['request'],
        'blog_page': context['blog_page'],
        'tags': tags
    }
```

I would like for `tags_list` to also be available  for other templates?

Yes I can just copy and paste the `def tags_list()`, edit the name and add the corresponding template via another `@register`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register it to work for all templates by registering a [**`simple_tag`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags), not an <s>`inclusion_tag`</s>:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def tags_list(context):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return {
        'request': context['request'],
        'blog_page': context['blog_page'],
        'tags': tags
    }
```

Now the context will be available in *all* templates. Since querysets are lazy, it will *not* make a query unless you iterate over it, or calculate the length for example.

Based on how you implement your template tag, it might make more sense to implement a [*context processor* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) instead of a template tag.

Comment: Okay I see! Am I correct to assume that cases for `inclusion_tag` are miniscule at best and only take in one template? I do use a context processor but only for the parent object.

Comment: @woof: I don't see why you can not do this for all templates. Since Django's querysets are lazy, if you do not *iterate/calculate the length/...* of a queryset, it will *not* make a database query.

Comment: The new plan is to use your method, removing the inclusion tag.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able to register the same function with multiple inclusion tags. Based off my reading of https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/template/library.py#L136 you should be able to just pass the same function through multiple decorators. You will want to name the tags differently to use different templates.

```py
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/components/tags_list_a.html',
                        name='a', takes_context=True)
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/components/tags_list_b.html',
                        name='b', takes_context=True)
def tags_list(context):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return {
        'request': context['request'],
        'blog_page': context['blog_page'],
        'tags': tags
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, for simplicity reasons I will be using Willem's answer, but this one works as well.